# Finding a more efficient heap sort?

Tags: java, sorting, complexity-theory, heapsort

Current I have a home work question which says,

> It is possible to make the heap sort algorithm more efficient by
>   writing a method that will order the entire list at once instead of
>   adding the elements one at a time.

However I can't figure out what exactly it means by "instead of adding elements one at a time", surely one has to building a heap first (which involves adding element from a unsorted list one by one), then remove the largest from the heap one at a time.

Here is my heap array:

```
import exceptions.exceptions.*;

public class ArrayHeap<T> extends ArrayBinaryTree<T> implements HeapADT<T> {

    public ArrayHeap(){
        super();
    }

    public void addElement (T element){
        if (count==size())
            expandCapacity();
        tree[count] = element;
        count++;
        if (count > 1)
            heapifyAdd();
    }

    private void heapifyAdd(){
        int index = count - 1;
        while ((index != 0) && (((Comparable)tree[index]).compareTo(tree[(index-1)/2]) < 0))
        {
            T temp = tree[index];
            tree[index] = tree[(index-1)/2];
            tree[(index-1)/2] = temp;
            index = (index-1)/2;
        }
    }

    public T removeMin(){
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Empty Heap");
        T minElement = findMin();
        tree[0] = tree[count-1];
        heapifyRemove();
        count--;
        return minElement;
    }

    private void heapifyRemove()
    {
        T temp;
        int node = 0;
        int left = 1;
        int right = 2;
        int next;

        if ((tree[left] == null) && (tree[right] == null))
           next = count;
        else if (tree[left] == null)
           next = right;
        else if (tree[right] == null)
           next = left;
        else if (((Comparable)tree[left]).compareTo(tree[right]) < 0)
           next = left;
        else
           next = right;
        while ((next < count) && (((Comparable)tree[next]).compareTo(tree[node]) < 0)){
                temp = tree[node];
                tree[node] = tree[next];
                tree[next] = temp;
                node = next;
                left = 2*node + 1;
                right = 2*(node+1);
                if ((tree[left] == null) && (tree[right] == null))
                   next = count;
                else if (tree[left] == null)
                   next = right;
                else if (tree[right] == null)
                   next = left;
                else if (((Comparable)tree[left]).compareTo(tree[right]) < 0)
                   next = left;
                else
                   next = right;
            }
    }

    public T findMin() {
        if (isEmpty())
           throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Empty Heap");
        return tree[0];
    }
}
```

Here is more HeapSort algorithm:

```
import ArrayHeap;

public class HeapSort<T>{

    public T[] heapsort(T[] data, int min, int max){
        ArrayHeap<T> temp = new ArrayHeap<T>();
        for (int c = min; c <= max; c++){
            temp.addElement(data[c]);
        }
        int count = min;
        while(!(temp.isEmpty())){
            T jj = temp.removeMin();
            data[count] = jj;
            count ++;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: I think they're asking you if you're able to find a sorting algorithm that is recursive because in the end you will have the whole ordered list instead of removing  the largest element from the heap one cycle (of a for loop) at a time. I would go for recursive Merge Sort

Comment: @VMMF thanks, I am not sure if the question wants a completely different method i.e. using quicksort or merge sort, or if it wants me to improve heapsort. Anyways, both merge and heap sort has average complexity O(nlogn), so where does the improvement in efficiency comes from?

Comment: Take a look at `Max-Heapify` and `Build-Max-Heap` functions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap. I think thats what They want You to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward way to perform heapsort is to use a *separate* heap and add all the elements to it, then the elements will be in order when we pop them out one by one. This is what "adding the elements one at a time" refers to in the statement, and this is what your implementation is doing: create a heap of type `ArrayHeap` and insert the elements of `data` to it, in the end pop the elements back to `data`.

A more efficient way (in terms of both space and time) is to perform in-place sorting, where we *use the array to be sorted as the heap*, rather than using additional memory for the heap, this is what "order the entire list at once" refers to. The steps of this implementation is as follow, we will order the elements in non-decreasing order:

1. We *max-heapify* the input array (i.e. we re-arrange the elements in the array so that it follows the max-heap property.
2. For `i` = n - 1 to 1:

   1. Swap the `0`-th element in the array with the `i`-th element.
   2. Decrease the size of the heap by 1 (i.e. the heap should be of size `i`).
   3. Perform the `sift-down` operation on the heap to restore the max-heap property.

Note that whenever the max-heap property holds, the top-most element in the heap is the largest element, so at the start of the `k`-th iteration (`k = n - i` here) the `0`-th element is the `k`-largest element, and we place is in the correct position in the array by swapping.

Note that step 1 can be done in `O(n)`, and in step 2 there are `O(n)` iterations and each `sift-down` operation takes time `O(log(n))`, so the overall time complexity is `O(n log(n))`.

Below is an implementation in Java for your reference:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HeapSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Iteration number %d%n", i));
            Integer[] array = randomIntArray(10, 0, 100);
            System.out.println(String.format("Array before sorting: [%s]", toStr(array)));
            heapSort(array);
            System.out.println(String.format("Array after sorting: [%s]", toStr(array)));
            System.out.println("================================================================");
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] heapSort(T[] array) {
        maxHeapify(array, array.length);

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            swap(array, 0, i);
            siftDown(array, i, 0);
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void maxHeapify(T[] array, int heapSize) {
        for (int i = getParentIdx(heapSize - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            siftDown(array, heapSize, i);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void siftDown(T[] array, int heapSize, int idx) {
        final int length = Math.min(array.length, heapSize) - 1;
        if (idx > length || idx < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index out of range");

        while (true) {
            int maxIdx = idx;
            int leftChildIdx = getLeftChildIdx(idx);
            int rightChildIdx = getRightChildIdx(idx);

            if (leftChildIdx <= length && array[maxIdx].compareTo(array[leftChildIdx]) < 0) maxIdx = leftChildIdx;
            if (rightChildIdx <= length && array[maxIdx].compareTo(array[rightChildIdx]) < 0) maxIdx = rightChildIdx;

            if (idx != maxIdx) {
                swap(array, idx, maxIdx);
                idx = maxIdx;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int getParentIdx(int idx) {
        return (idx - 1) / 2;
    }

    private static int getLeftChildIdx(int idx) {
        return idx * 2 + 1;
    }

    private static int getRightChildIdx(int idx) {
        return idx * 2 + 2;
    }

    private static <T> void swap(T[] array, int i, int j) {
        T tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }

    private static <T> String toStr(T[] array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (T element : array) {
            sb.append(element + ", ");
        }

        return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 2);
    }

    private static Integer[] randomIntArray(int size, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        Integer[] result = new Integer[size];
        Random random = new Random();
        int diff = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) result[i] = lowerBound + random.nextInt(diff);
        return result;
    }
}
```